How adjust armature mesh by mdd cache mesh
i have two meshes, one with armature modifier, another with shape key sequence from mdd cache, i need correct first (armatured) mesh by adding some shape keys, that should copy form from second mesh on selected frame. Modifier  shrinkwrap don't work, not apply as shape key, not save as shape key - both incorrect with armature modifier. I try manually add new shape key, set it in max value and after that in sculpting mode shrink to second mesh, but can`t find how... Is some ideas how to resolve?
